# Sequence of random variable converges to zero but expectation converges to infinity

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, expected-value

I am currently working on a problem from a Probability Theory course:

Construct a sequence of random variables $\xi_n$ such that $\xi_n(\omega) \rightarrow 0$ for every $\omega$, but $\mathbb{E} \xi \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow 0$.

I find really hard to construct such a sequence given that I don't even know the probability measure of each $\omega$. Does each $\xi_n$ have to be a constant function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_n(t)=n^{2}I_{(0,\frac 1 n)}$ on the space $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure. Then $X_n(t) \to 0$ for every $t$ and $EX_n=n$.

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain what you mean $I_{(0, \frac{1}{n})}$? Is it the length of the interval $(0, \frac{1}{n})$? If so, why does $X_n(t) \rightarrow 0$ for every $t$ (it seems $X_n(t) = n$ for every $t$)?

Comment: $X_n(t)$ is $n^{2}$ for $t$ between $0$ and $\frac 1 n$ and $0$ elsewhere. Note that for any $t \in (0,1)$ $X_n(t)=0$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: Many thanks for the help!